# AWS EC2 django file creation permission error

Tags: django, ubuntu, permissions, apache2

AWS EC2 Django help needed.

my django backend has function wherein a file is created with :
f = open("xyz.txt", "w")
when i run it with runserver command on ec2 aws it runs fine.
but when i run it with apache it says permission denied and give me an error

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the folder structure of your application, including the owner and group

Comment: i tried everything
chmod 777
chown www-data:www-data

but it didn't work @ChrisWilliams

Comment: Have you seen this https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=301607

Comment: Already tried it @AzyCrw4282

Comment: thankyou @ChrisWilliams  thanks i've solved my issue like given below'

Comment: Glad you solved this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the error by moving the django project to /var/www folder and running the chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/django_proj